# Append string based on condition python

Tags: python-3.x

I just want to append strings based on my condition. For example all strings starting with http won't be appended but all the other strings in each that has a length of 40 will be appended.

```
    words = []
    store1 = []
   disregard = ["http","gen"]

    for all in glob.glob(r'MYDIR'):
        with open(all, "r",encoding="utf-16") as f:
            text = f.read()
        lines = text.split("\n")

        for each in lines:
            words += each.split()
        for each in words:
            if len(each) == 40 and each not in disregard:
                store1.append(each)
```

Update:

```
if disregard[0] not in each:
```

works but how can I compare it to all the contents in my list? using disregard only doesnt work 
Here is my input text file :

```
http://1234ashajkhdajkhdajkhdjkaaaaaaad1
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
genp://1234ashajkhdajkhdajkhdjkaaaaaaad1
a\a
```

The only thing that will append will be "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

Comment: I didn't find anything wrong in your code. Try change `each not in disregard` to `all([word not in each for word in disregard])` because I think when you split words, "http" not stand itself but like `"http://blablabla.com"` because there's no space there and it makes `each not in disregard` return `True`.

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object it no callable when I tried replacing it.

Comment: Ah... it's because you are using `all` as variable in `for all in glob.glob(r'MYDIR')`. Better change it because `all` is python function.

Comment: You could add an example of data, the output you currently get from it, and the output you want from it. This would make your question clearer.

Comment: updated .............

Comment: A description of your variables would also be helpful. For example, it looks like `store1` is for your output? And `words` is a temporary array of what you're looking at in each loop (in which case the declaration should be *inside* the `glob` loop, not outside it)? But what are `Storage`, `getwords`, and `All1`? Better to either explain them or remove them.

Comment: will remove them

Comment: First thing: looks like there's an indentation problem: the line `for each in words:` and subsequents should be moved to the left (to the same level as your main loop `for all in glob.glob(r'MYDIR'):`, it only needs to execute once this main loop is over).

Comment: Are you intending for there to be one possible result per line, or can there be multiple results in a line, separated by spaces?

Comment: Second thing: the condition `each not in disregard` should be turned to `not any([each in w for w in disregard])` or even `not any([each.startswith(w) for w in disregard])` if you only want to keep the lines that do not start with the disregarded strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers should depend on the number of words you want to disregard.
It's important to define what word means. If the word ends with spaces, should they all be stripped?
One solution could be to create a regular expression from all your words and use that to match the line.

```
import glob
import re

disregard = ["http","gen"]
pattern = "|".join([re.escape(w) for w in disregard])
for all in glob.glob(r'MYDIR/*'):
    with open(all, "r", encoding="utf-16") as f:
        matched_words = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            if len(line) == 40 and not re.match(pattern, line):
                matched_words.append(line)

    print(matched_words)
```

Comment: This solution has an edge case where the last line in the file (which won't end with `\n`) could be 41 characters and erroneously pass these conditions. Or it could be 40 characters and fail.

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure looks ok, it seems the place where it's breaking is setting up incorrect conditionals. You say you want to check where each line *starts* with the supplied strings, but then you split each line and check for *existence* of those strings. Use `.startswith()` instead. This will also make it so there doesn't have to be a space after "http" in order for that string to be caught.

Also, either the conditional testing should be placed after the loop that builds the words list, or else the words list should be reset at the start of each loop so you're not re-testing words you've already checked.

```
# adjusted some variable names for clarity
words = []
output = []
disregard = ["http","gen"]

for fname in glob.glob(r'MYDIR'):
    with open(fname, "r", encoding="utf-16") as f:
        text = f.read()
    lines = text.split("\n")

    for line in lines:
        words += line.split()

for word in words:
    if len(word) == 40 and not any([word.startswith(dis) for dis in disregard]):
        output.append(each)
```

Comment: What if I want to store all the the string that starts with disregard?

Comment: Just use `any(...)` instead of `not any(...)`.